# I want to have multiple streams (up to 4) on one YouTube Live broadcast, Is that possible?

Tags: youtube

I want to have multiple streams (up to 4) on one YouTube Live broadcast, Is that possible ?

It would be a news cast report with up to 4 reporters from separate locations discussing the weather.

Comment: not sure about youtube, but I'm pretty sure google hangouts can do this.

Comment: Interesting idea! And it seems as though there would be someone in a "director" role switching between the feeds at the appropriate time...?

Comment: You can do this by using a vision switcher (preferably a hardware one), and then sending the mixed/switched feed to the computer that is streaming to YouTube Live. I don't have details of *how*, so I won't make an answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use something like a M/E switcher with a multiviewer to do this. Just feed the program out into the computer you are streaming from using an input card.

I have not used youtube streaming, but I know that justin.tv or other streaming services can use something like OBS to switch between scenes which you can setup with different video inputs in different configurations on the stream.

As these all rely on having external gear to get the camera feeds to the streaming location, the google hangout solution would be the best, as I am assuming you are on a low budget

Answer (score 2):

You want to start an Event, it support multiple cameras.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853812?hl=en

You'll also need either a program that supports send multiple streams or a program that can be opened in multiple sessions and that way send multiple streams.

I strongly recommend OBS Studio.